# use External database in android

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I have created database AddressBookMaster.db using Sqlite Browser and also create table AddressBook in mentioned database. But now problem is that I want to use this .db file in my application so where should I put this db file and how to fetch in application?

Is there any example or tutorial which can help to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information contained in [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) should have exactly what you are looking for.

You should note that while this is not really difficult it is not just a set of trivial commands that would be done outside of your application.

Answer (score 5):

You can put your Database file in the SDcard also. Use following code to use the Database from the SDCard.

```
File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/Your_db_File.db" ); 
SQLiteDatabase  db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
```

Comment: Notice that you need to include `<uses-permission>` of writing/reading external storage !! I spent hours debugging unknowing error to discover that.

Answer (score 0):

The information contained in "Using your own SQLite database in Android applications" is very userful for U and If U have db with more than 1024 bytes size then first split db into small parts and copy that all small dbs in your application dirrectory .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but problem is How can i split db? Nandlal virani form S. K. Patel Institute am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Use [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), to fill (initialize) the database of your app on installation

If You want to change the default folder of the database to sdcard:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        SQLiteOpenHelper helper = ..
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase()
    }


    @Override
    public File getDatabasePath(String name) {
        return new File(getDatabasePathString(name));
    }

    @Override
    public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
        return super.openOrCreateDatabase(getDatabasePathString(name), mode, factory);
    }

    @Override
    public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        return super.openOrCreateDatabase(getDatabasePathString(name), mode, factory, errorHandler);
    }

    /*Put the default folder to store database of your application / or activity here */
    public String getDatabasePathString(String name) {
        return getExternalCacheDir()+ "/" + name+".db";  /* /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/cache */
    }

}
```