# Is it possible to read/write to SQLite on a removable USB Flash Drive for Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to read/write to SQLite on a removable USB Flash Drive from Android, by this I mean the app is installed on the phone, but the data used by the app would be stored on a removable USB flash drive that plugs into the USB/Charging port.

I have been reading a lot and for the most part references to this suggest the data must be in the same location as the app. I need the data to be external to the app so different databases can be used as required. If it is possible I would appreciate a reference to an example or information.

> unfortunately the [use-external-database-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360166/use-external-database-in-android) article requires the database to be located in the Assets /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases It needs to be copied every time from the source location. It also is not suitable for large data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use External database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360166/use-external-database-in-android)

Comment: @leoderprofi  No unfortunately that article requires the database to be located in the Assets  /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases  It needs to be copied every time from the source location. It also is not suitable for large data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706036/sqlite-database-in-external-micro-sdcard

really as long as your app can access the data you are golden.You store it at any location you know. If you dont use any kind of file picker and let the user decide.

Comment: I know that this is not a 100% solution,but it surely leads you to the right problems to solve.